# How to initialize a property added to object prototype with constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, initialization, prototype

I know it is possible to write something like this:
    `MyObj.prototype.someNewProperty = "some new value";`

How can I initialize the newly added property with a parameter passed to the constructor of the object rather than a fixed literal value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to initialize a property added to object prototype with constructor?

You wouldn't do that at all. An instance-specific property, that is initialised on a per-instance basis, has to be put as an own property of the instance. You don't put it on the prototype object, it makes no sense to let all instances inherit it.

So just initialise it in the constructor only as you always would:

```
function Example(arg) {
    this.someNewProperty = arg;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I infer from your answer that adding properties to JS object prototype is analogous to declaring static class members (as in C++ for example). Is that right?

Comment: No, properties of the prototype are static but instance members. There's no good analogue in C++ or other class-based languages. The prototype object is what each instance does inherit properties from (typically methods).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am not yet accustomed to JS way of OOP.